# Визуальное оформление графика (chart) на C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Как на контроле `chart` отметить маркерами точки? А то получается просто ломаная линия, не очень красиво. Не понимаю какое свойство использовать. Пробовал `chart1.EmptyPointStyle = ...` и `chart1.Marker...`, но ничего не получилось.

Comment: Winforms или WPF?

Comment: winforms (меньше 15 символов)

Answer (score 2):

Однако заработало:

```
.MarkerSize = 9;
.MarkerColor = Color.Red;
.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
```